# Mongoose watch function - The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, changestream

I'm trying to implement the mongoose `watch` function because I want to update some fields in the `users` collection when `clients` collection is updated, so I have this in my schema file:

```js
// ... schema code omitted for brevity.

const clientsCollection = mongoose.model('Client', clientSchema);

clientsCollection.watch<Client>([], { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' }).on('change', updateUser);
```

Inside `updateUser` (which is in the same file) I'm trying to get the result of summing the field `clientSalesValue` for all the documents that pertains to the user with id `abc123`:

```js
async function updateUser(data: ChangeStreamDocument<Client>) {
  //... some other not relevant code

  const result = await clientsCollection.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { userId: new ObjectId('abc123') }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        totalSaleValue: { $sum: '$clientSalesValue' }
      }
    },
    {
      $unset: ['_id']
    }
  ]).exec();

  //... here goes the code that updates the user collection
}
```

But **as soon as I save the file** I get this error from node:

```js
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received undefined
```

The issue lies in the **aggregate** part, **if I comment all that part node doesn't yell anymore**.

What I infer from the error message is that I'm passing `undefined` to the `on` listener but that's clearly not the case, I'm passing an actual function.

Now it is true that my function is implicitly returning undefined (from a Promise) because I'm not returning anything explicitly but the error persist even if I return something.

So what I'm missing here?

Comment: Where is `updateUser` function written ? Is it in the same file? If not do you import/require it the correct way?

Comment: it is in another file but that's not the issue, all the import and exports are working just fine, like I mentioned if I comment the `aggregate` part then the issue disappears. But for the sake of simplicity I will join all the code in the same file, I will edit the op.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is to pass the function inside a callback, it seems that I was interpreting the error message wrong.

The listener have to be a function. I was passing a function but that function returns a value (the returned one from it) at the end on the day.

This is the working code:

```js
clientsCollection.watch<Client>([], { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' }).on('change', (data) => updateUser(data));
```